# How to get button value chosen by the user and use it on the controller in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, web

I am new with php and laravel and I have a problem:

How to get a button value chosen by the user and use it on the controller to retrieve specific information from database.

I get the "termkey" from the database and I need to know the value selected by the user.

This is my view :

[image: view]

[image: controller]

Comment: please add code instead of images

Comment: you didn't have `value` attribute for your button, please specify it for your button

Comment: used jquery onclick event form submit and pass button value and then you can get into the controller

Comment: Add a hidden input rather than placing the value on the button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<button name="termkey">{{ $ca->termkey }}</button>
```

change the upper to

```
<button name="termkey" value="{{ $ca->termkey }}">{{ $ca->termkey }}</button>
```

then in controller

```
$request->input('termkey');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use value attribute in your button tag and why there is a closing anchor tag I don't understand. IN value attribute u can set any kind of value you want. then u can access it in the controller like you did

```
<button type="submit" name="termKey" value="{{$c->termKey}} "><span class="badge">{{$c->total}}</span></button>
```

And please always try to paste code not image